# How to increase the efficiency of the follownig code

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

Can any one please help me optimize the following simple code
It takes forever to complete the execution.
Maybe I am running into an infinite loop somewhere.
What it does is just takes two strings if they're equal then it shuffles the position according to the mentioned cells here.

```
 Sub sort()

 Dim astid As String
 Dim partno As String
 Dim FinalRow As Long
 Dim i, j As Integer

 FinalRow = Sheets("Combined Version").Range("H9000").End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 5 To FinalRow

    partno = Sheets("Combined Version").Cells(i, 7).Value

    For j = 5 To FinalRow

       astid = Sheets("Combined Version").Cells(j, 8).Value

        If astid = partno Then

            Cells(j, 8).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("N5").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            Cells(i, 8).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(j, 8).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            Range("N5").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Cells(i, 8).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End If

    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This should be asked at Code Review

Comment: `End(xlUp).Row` will give you top cell in H column i.e. first row! Are you looking for last one! the loop is going to be infinite as the value for j and i is going to increase!!

Comment: @MarmiK - the i and j are row numbers. The 8 in `Cells(i, 8)` notes the 8th column (aka column H). See [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of an iterim N5 as a temporary holding area was unnecessary as you had already stored the value in the *astid* var.

```
Sub mysort()
    Dim astid As String, partno As String
    Dim fr As Long, i, j As Long

    With Sheets("Combined Version")
        fr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 5 To fr
            partno = .Cells(i, 7).Value2
            For j = 5 To fr
                astid = .Cells(j, 8).Value2
                If LCase(astid) = LCase(partno) Then
                    .Cells(j, 8) = .Cells(i, 8).Value2
                    .Cells(i, 8) = astid
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The use of the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) reduces the repeated calls to identify the worksheet.

This could be made faster with variant arrays.

Comment: Still it's running for the last 2 minutes is there no other way to make it execute fast ?Also it takes a lot of the cpu resources heats up the processors a little bit  ...

Comment: If you are asking if it can be made faster then yes; I explained that above. Supply some before and after sample data and I may see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are scanning every row in the worksheet for every row you work down!  This could be improved further with a `Find` that selects all cells in the column that match and then you simply enumerate them.  Check out Chip Pearson's `FindAll` function to get help on this. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/FindAll.aspx

Also, you are using the clipboard a lot unnecessarily.  You only need to hold the values in variables whilst you do the switch.

Try this out (using the same structure you had without the optimized "FindAll" option):-

```
Sub sort()

 Dim astid As String
 Dim partno As String
 Dim FinalRow As Long
 Dim i, j As Integer

 Dim Cell_I As String
 Dim Cell_J As String

 Dim ws As Worksheet

 'Don't update the screen until the end
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

 Set ws = Sheets("Combined Version")

 FinalRow = ws.Range("H9000").End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 5 To FinalRow

    partno = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value

    For j = 5 To FinalRow

       astid = ws.Cells(j, 8).Value

        If astid = partno Then

            Cell_I = ws.Cells(i, 8).Value
            Cell_J = ws.Cells(j, 8).Value

            ws.Cells(j, 8).Value = Cell_I
            ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = Cell_J

        End If

    Next j
Next i

Set ws = Nothing    

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```